# ACF gives a syntaxError unexpected token <

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF plugin and overall it's working great.

Expect for one small part:

I've got a WYSIWYG text box on a page where I add a few enters, but when I look at the console I get an unexpected token < error:

```
<?php the_field('correctoutput'); ?>
```

WHen I try to use the below part is just breaks:

```
<?php echo the_field('correctoutput'); ?>
```

When I use it also breaks:

```
<?php echo json_encode the_field('correctoutput'); ?>
```

This completely breaks the page:

```
<?php get_field('correctoutput'); ?>
```

It should add some text to a div when it's correct:

```
 $('#correcto').innerHTML (<?php the_field('correctoutput'); ?>);
```

I've also used .text

The only way it works is to catch it in a variable:

```
<?php $correctoutput = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'correctoutput', true ); 
?>
```

and then output it:

```
<?php echo json_encode ($correctoutput); ?>
```

But this will remove the `<p></p>` tags... and that's also what is giving the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape your content before outputting in within some other piece of code. What is most likely happening here is something like this:

```
$('correcto').innerHTML('bla bla <a href='http://example.com'>some link</a>');
```

Or something like above, which will break the syntax. By using `esc_html` you can resolve the issue:

```
$('#correcto').innerHTML ('<?php echo esc_html( get_field("correctoutput") ); ?>');
```

### Two extra notes

1. `the_field` echos the value of your field. You don't need another
   echo. If you want to return the value, use `get_field` instead.
2. Always wrap your value (even if it's a function) in parentheses. So you should use `json_encode( get_field('correctoutput') );` ( Yes, `get_field`, not `the_field`! )

Answer (score -1):

You're missing quotes around the content of innerHTML.

If correctoutput is `<div></div>`, then you're script looks like this:

```
 $('#correcto').innerHTML(<div></div>);
```

Which is invalid, because you're missing quotes. innerHTML needs a string, which is in quotes in JavaScript. That first `<` is where your error is coming from. So you need to do this:

```
 $('#correcto').innerHTML('<?php the_field('correctoutput'); ?>');
```

Which would create:

```
 $('#correcto').innerHTML('<div></div>');
```

`json_encode` doesn't cause the error because the result is a valid JavaScript type, which `<div></div>`, sans quotes, isn't.